Getting a ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule error when building the android app of a react-native app
I am currently facing an issue and cannot determine why I am encountering an error originating from the ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule node module. I’ve tried to analyze the situation, but the root cause of the error remains unclear to me. It seems to be related to the way the module is functioning or interacting with my application, but I am struggling to pinpoint the exact problem or find a solution. Any insight or guidance on why this error might be occurring would be greatly appreciated.
When I start building the app on android studio, I am getting the following errors from the ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule:
                    if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException collEx) {
                                                                               ^
/Users/rasangalk/Documents/Rooster/mobile/rooster-mobile-application/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/auth/ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java:1621: error: not a statement
                    if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException collEx) {
                                                                                ^
/Users/rasangalk/Documents/Rooster/mobile/rooster-mobile-application/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/auth/ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java:1621: error: ';' expected
                    if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException collEx) {
                                                                                      ^

Here is my build.gradle:

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        kotlinVersion = "1.7.10"

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
        classpath ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9")
    }
}

and here is my andoid/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

also my dependencies from the  package.json:
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.19.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "20",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "20",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "20",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "20",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "20",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.20",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "eventemitter3": "^5.0.1",
    "haversine": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nanoid": "^5.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.7",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-eject": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.3",
    "twrnc": "^3.6.5"
  },```

